# Why is mongoose not allowing me to find by $in on _id unless I have a schema wrapping another schema?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, graphql

Please, if anyone can help explain the below situation. I've lost hours only to discover a working solution but it doesn't make sense why it needs to be implemented this way.

For some reason if I connect mongo over nodejs, using 1 mongoose schema, I cannot search via $in.
When I wrap that single schema in another schema, with no additional information $in returns a match.

Note: the command line works always. So it is something to do with the way the schema needs to be impelemnted.

I am new to mongoose so maybe there is something obvious i am missing but it does not make any sense. Any help appreciated.
thanks

## creation of data in docker

#### Note there is only one record:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
mongo <<EOF
use ${MONGO_DB_NAME}
db.createCollection("persons")
db.persons.insert({"name": "CPU"})
EOF
```

## schema.ts

```js
import { Model, Schema, Document, Connection } from 'mongoose';

interface IPerson {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
};

type TSchemaPerson = Schema<IPerson>;

const SchemaPerson: TSchemaPerson = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String
});

// ##########################################################################
// ODD BEHAVIOUR ?
// I have to wrap SchemaPerson inside SchemaPersons, 
// even though its basically a duplication in order to get $in to return a result
// --------------------------------------------------------
//                                                         \/
const SchemaPersons: Schema<TSchemaPerson> = new Schema({SchemaPerson});
// ##########################################################################

const collectionName: string = 'Person';

export type TDocumentPerson = Model<Document & IPerson>;
export type TConnPersons = (con: Connection) => TDocumentPerson;

// ##########################################################################
// ODD BEHAVIOUR ?
// If I return SchemaPerson instead of SchemaPersons here then $in does not return a result --------
//                                                                        \/
const ModelPersons: TConnPersons = con => con.model(collectionName, SchemaPersons);
// ##########################################################################

export default ModelPersons;
```

## graphql - resolver.ts

```js
const persons: QueryResolvers['persons'] = async (parent, args, context) => {
  console.log('persons()');

  const { dbConn }: IContext = context;

  if (dbConn) {
    const Person: TDocumentPerson = ModelPersons(dbConn);
    let result;
    let resultIn;
    try {
      result = await Person.find().exec();
      console.log('result = ', result); // Result in both cases = [ { _id: 5f36e199ebd39f53b437834b, name: 'CPU' } ]

      resultIn = await Person.find({
        _id: {
          $in: [new ObjectId('5f36e199ebd39f53b437834b')]
        }
      }).exec(); 
// ##########################################################################
// ODD BEHAVIOUR ?
    // Result with SchemaPersons = [ { _id: 5f36e199ebd39f53b437834b, name: 'CPU' } ]
    // Result with SchemaPerson = [ ]
      console.log('resultIn = ', resultIn);
// ##########################################################################
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err = ', err);
    }
  }
};
```

## Note if I change the model to a collection then it does work. See below:

## schema.ts - connecting as collection

```js
import { Schema, Collection, Connection } from 'mongoose';
interface IPerson {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
};

type TSchemaPerson = Schema<IPerson>;

const SchemaPerson: TSchemaPerson = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String
});


export type TCollectionPersons = Collection & IPerson;
export type TConnPersons = (con: Connection) => TCollectionPersons;
const CollectionPersons: TConnPersons = con => con.collection('persons', SchemaPerson)

export default CollectionPersons;
```

## resolver.ts

```js
const persons: TCollectionPersons = CollectionPersons(dbConn);

    let result;
    let resultIn;
    let resultById
    try {
      result = await persons.find().toArray();
      console.log('result = ', result);
       // Result [ { _id: 5f36e199ebd39f53b437834b, name: 'CPU' } ]
  
      resultIn = await persons.find({
        _id: {
          $in: [new ObjectId('5f36e199ebd39f53b437834b')]
        }
      }).toArray();
      console.log('resultIn = ', resultIn);
    // Result [ { _id: 5f36e199ebd39f53b437834b, name: 'CPU' } ]

      // cannot use findById on collection.
      // resultById = await persons.findById('5f36e199ebd39f53b437834b');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err = ', err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What queries are actually being generated and sent?

Comment: Its nota graphql problem. I only added this for context. The problem is somehow related to my mongo connection how I'm using mongoose schema and maybe typescript.

Comment: Right. What MongoDB queries are being sent?

Comment: Its in the example above: resultIn = await Person.find({
        _id: {
          $in: [new ObjectId('5f36e199ebd39f53b437834b')]
        }
      }).exec();

Comment: And what is the data in the collection?

Comment: Its literally what you see in the example. I have one row only: use dbname: db.createCollection("persons");
db.persons.insert({"name": "CPU"}); the id is dynamically added via mongo as. 5f36e199ebd39f53b437834b. When i search via cli:  db.persons.find({ _id: { $in: [new ObjectId('5f36e199ebd39f53b437834b')] } } it correctly returns array.

Comment: Okay, so are you saying the constructed query is wrong or the query is correct but doesn't find expected data?

Comment: the query is correct. It doesn't return the expected data. It should return an item in the array

Comment: Also - resultById = await persons.findById(new ObjectId('5f36e199ebd39f53b437834b')); // returns null

Comment: In that case remove everything mongoose related and use mongo shell to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Mongo shell works.

Comment: You just said you are not getting expected data, which is it then?

Comment: mongo shell works. Mongoose over npm however seems to be the problem

Comment: I've raised a ticket with them anyway. Will see what happens with that and update this once I have feedback